# Issue transferring multipart file to another location

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm attempting to use the `transferTo` method on a MultipartFile, but I'm having issues in doing so. Below is my code:

```
String videoName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

File tempVideoFile = new File("src/main/resources/static/campaigns/" + videoName);
//multipart file is video
video.transferTo(tempVideoFile); //this line is what causes an error
```

This ends up throwing an `IOException` saying the JVM cannot find the path specified. Here's the error:

```
Invalid file directoryjava.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Jake\workspace\Test App\src\main\resources\static\temp\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\Test App\src\main\resources\static\campaigns\db95aad3-a3ba-489a-a02e-83f5beece9a7 (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Not 100% certain as to why it's not working but I believe the proper directory should be `src\main\resources\static\campaigns\db95aad3-a3ba-489a-a02e-83f5beece9a7` instead of the one inside of the Tomcat directory, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas as to why this won't work? The path `src\main\resources\static\campaigns\` exists so I'm not sure why.

Comment: Use an absolute path. Don't rely on the directory from which Tomcat is started. And don't store data that the user uploads in the sources of your project. That makes no sense. Once deployed, all you'll have is a war file deployed under tomcat. No source project. And even then, uplodaded data is not part of the project sources. It's data.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm going to be hosting on AWS so I don't think I can use an absolute path. And I'm not storing it in the source directory. I'm copying the multipart file to the source temporarily so I can check the video length, create a thumbnail, upload to AWS, and then I delete the temporary file. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Again, once deployed, you won't have any source directory. Sources only exist on the developers workstations. Not on production machines. If there even is a file system on AWS, then create a real temporary file, on a location that is guaranteed to exist and be writable for temp files: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-. Or in a configurable directory that you know will exist in production.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay. Thank you. I'll look into that. If you want to make a top level answer, I'll accept it.